# Unable to use phangorn::phyDat

Tags: r, phylogenetics

I am following an example from ‘Analysis of Phylogenetics Second Edition and Evolution with R’ from Emmanuel Paradis.

He is doing:

[image]

I am doing pretty much the same:

```
x=c('garras','garras','garras', 'tejido','tejido','tejido')
y <- phyDat(matrix(x), "USER", levels = unique(x))
```

but I get:

> Error in phyDat.default(data, levels = levels, return.index =
> return.index, : data object must contain taxa names

Screenshot:

[image]

What am I doing wrong? how come the example from the book works...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I cannot access the book, it might be an older version or there are some steps in between. The screen shot doesn't help.

If you look at the [vignette](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/phangorn/vignettes/phangorn-specials.pdf) and the error, what you need to provide is a matrix of characters with defined row names, for example:

```
set.seed(111)
x = sample(letters,100,replace=TRUE)
phyDat(matrix(x),"USER",levels=unique(x))

Error in phyDat.default(data, levels = levels, return.index = return.index,  : 
  data object must contain taxa names

mat = matrix(x,10,10,dimnames=list(paste0("t",1:10),NULL))
phyDat(mat,"USER",levels=unique(x))
10 sequences with 10 character and 10 different site patterns.
The states are n t s o y e c h z q m j d o h n z y x p q g u o a i h y c g t d f y t d f e u e f d i j r z x w u m a j p j g d t q y v o x p m s o z x z a y j z r u s a y k l f g l f r i l r f m t t e f x v f g q j
```